# Daemon Thread [HouseKeeper] (Suspended (exception IndexOutOfBoundsException))ArrayList<E>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Each time when I deploy my project by eclipse, the debug view show this, what's more, the web page could work normally, but the debug view still show this **Daemon Thread** message.

This problem came up recently. I'm confused that what cause this problem?

Is it the reason that `ArrayList` is not thread-safe? The screenshot is here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. This problem is cause by the tomcat launch mode in myeclispe. If you are using myeclipse, please select **Window** -->**Preferences**-->**Tomcat**-->**Tomcat 7.x**-->**Launch** change the launch mode to Run Mode. (You should choose the right version of Tomcat which you're using)